# Snowflake to_geometry with allowInvalid is not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, gis, geojson

I have a bunch of valid geometry objects validated using `st_isvalid` and I try to combine them using an UDF and then calling `to_geometry` to get back the result as a geometry.

Code:

```
select to_geometry(st_asgeojson(combine_geoms(ARRAY_AGG(st_asgeojson(geom_simplified)))), TRUE) as geom_1 from tbl where condition;
```

UDF relevant code (used in many other places):

```
mapping(unary_union([shape(i) for i in geoms]))
```

There are 2 versions of the same geom, both valid: original and simplified (with `st_simplify` to be able to store in a cell as `geometry` due to the 16MB size limit).

With the original version I can combine them but I cannot combine them all as there are too many points - 16mb limit.

With the simplified version, I am getting: `Geography validation failed: Loop 0: Edge X crosses edge Y`.

I thought that using the `allowInvalid` flag in `to_geometry` will ignore this kind of intersection.

To mention that I successfully used the flag before when loading geoms as varchar from another DB to SF as geometry. Lots of invalid ones but could be stored in SF in the end.

Relevant doc: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-geospatial#allowing-conversion-functions-to-create-invalid-shapes

Is this the right behavior or can someone tell me what else I could try to avoid that intersection issue?

Thanks in advance!

FIX:
Changed the function to return `STRING` instead of `GEOGRAPHY` and returned only `unary_union([shape(i) for i in geoms])` from the UDF, not enclosed in the `mapping`.
Then, in SF I am using the `to_geometry` with the `allowInvalid` flag, which works as expected.

Comment: Looks as if `sp_simplify` is not on the list of functions that support the `allowInvalid` option: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-geospatial#allowing-conversion-functions-to-create-invalid-shapes. It does show that `to_geometry` supports it, but I wonder if the function reporting the invalid geometry may be on the step using `sp_simplify`?

Comment: I am applying `st_simplify` to create `geom_simplified` from `geom` so it happens before this step. I would say it's not from that. What I know for sure is that the `allowInvalid` flag is a very new SF feature, around 6 months old.

Comment: This definitely seems like something that's worth opening a Support case. If you have a sample invalid geom that can reproduce this in a minimal sample, I can open an internal ticket if you'd prefer.

Comment: found the issue: should have paid more attention to the exception. `Geography validation failed`. So the issue is that the UDF returns a GEOGRAPHY type which cannot be represented as it is invalid, so it is not even reaching the `to_geometry` function.